# Sharepoint CAML choice query returns the same value

Tags: 2010, caml

I'm trying to take records from a list, based on Article Type field, which value type is choice. The problem is, that no matter what I'm giving as a type in query, result is still the same. I ran it through CAML builder, and there it's working perfectly fine. When i change a query to run on a title field, it gives the proper value based on what parameter i provide. An ideas what is wrong? Here is the code:

```
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
public class NewestCategoryArticle : WebPart
{
    private Label Body = new Label();
    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        try
        {

            SPList NewsList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["News"];
            if (NewsList == null)
                return;
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Article_x0020_Type' /><Value Type='Choice'>"+CategoryName+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
            SPListItemCollection Items = NewsList.GetItems(query);
            if (Items.Count > 0)
            {
                SPListItem NewItem = Items[0];
                foreach (SPListItem item in Items)
                {
                    if (item != null)
                        NewItem = item;
                }
                Title = NewItem["Title"].ToString();
                string title = (string)NewItem.Title.ToString();
                string author = (string)NewItem["Author"].ToString();
                string content = (string)NewItem["Body"].ToString();
                Body.Text = "<h1>" + title + " " + author + "</h1> \n\n\n" + content;
                this.Controls.Add(Body);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    public static string CategoryName;
    [Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared), WebBrowsable(true), WebDisplayName("News")]
    public string _CategoryText
    {
        get { return CategoryName; }
        set { CategoryName = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the `<Query>` tag.

Your CAML query should be as below:

```
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Article_x0020_Type' /><Value Type='Choice'>"+CategoryName+"</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly fine. Can you tell me why is that in those tags it provided wrong result?

Comment: Caml Builder includes Query tag which should not be there when using server-side C# code and CAML . The syntax was wrong basically. So, next time just ensure that before running CAML query in c# code, remove the `<Query>` tag